# Netwire instead of Control.Monad?

Tags: haskell

As I learn to use Netwire, I've noticed that it contains several functions with the same names as ones in Control.Monad. (ie `when`, `unless`) How orthogonal are they? Does using Netwire make Control.Monad redundant?

For example, a simple game's main loop code might look like

```
main = mainloop
    where mainloop = do
              processEvents
              swapBuffers
              shouldQuit <- gotQuitEvent
              unless shouldQuit mainloop
```

Is there a netwire-ish way to write this, or should I do this in standard monadic style?

Comment: Check out http://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2013-08-01-getting-started-with-netwire-and-sdl.html#rendering-with-sdl

Comment: The Netwire library wouldn't work without `Control.Monad`.  Arguably, `Control.Monad` is more powerful because it will allow you to manipulate and build a larger number of monads than Netwire will, since Netwire is just a monad.  Netwire is specialized for certain tasks, while Monads are generic mathematical structures.  You can't really compare them.  It would be like asking if the Lens library was more powerful than `Data.Functor`.

Comment: @bheklilr Good point. I have edited the title of my question.

Comment: @Dan Looking at the source for `Control.Wire.Interval` (where `unless` and `when` are located), it's really just implemented by wrapping the predicate in new function that returns an `Either` instead of a `Bool`, then wrapping that in a constructor for `Wire`.  Pretty simple stuff, actually.

Comment: At least until version 4.0.7, monadic style seemed to be the way to go, as shown by [their own examples](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/netwire-4.0.7/docs/Control-Wire.html#g:2). However, the most recent version (5.0.0) had API changes, and I'm not sure anymore what's the recommended way to run wires. [The documentation](http://hub.darcs.net/ertes/netwire) doesn't provide any complete example.